# Как вывести записи из определенной рубрики wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Имеется вот такой код, не получается ввести записи определенной рубрики

```
<?php
                        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        $argument=array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'category' => 2,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => 6,
                            'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
                            );
                        $my_query = null;
                        $my_query = new WP_Query($argument);
                        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="single_news">
    <a href="#">
      <?php
                if (function_exists('add_theme_support') ) {
                  the_post_thumbnail( array(250,99999));
                }
              ?>
      <p class="date_publish"><? the_time('d.m.y') ?></p>
      <p class="title_news"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    </a>
  </div>
 <?php   endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В цикле нет же [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) - выводить нечего.

Comment: мне контент выводить не надо, я вывожу только загаловок новости, дату публикации и картинку новости

Comment: Так что, `<?php the_title(); ?>` не выводиться? Или что? Вопрос понятней сформулируйте.  "не получается" - это ни о чем. Что нужно-то и что получается.

Answer (score 0):

А нет никакой ошибки?
Насколько помню, `'caller_get_posts'=> 1` уже не используется - замените на
`'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`

Comment: Не помогло, все равно выводить все записи что есть на сайте а не отдельной рубрики